# Flutter doctor no reconoce la instalación de Android Studio

Tags: flutter

Tengo Android Studio instalado, pero `flutter doctor` no lo reconoce.

[image: Este es el error.]

Además, me sale la otra advertencia de `android toolchain`.

Answer (score 0):

Esto se soluciona agregando la ruta donde tienes instalado Android Studio de la siguiente manera. `flutter config --android-studio-dir="C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio"`. Pero esto puede desencadenar el siguiente problema al ejecutar nuevamente ´flutter doctor´.

[image: Segunda advertencia en flutter doctor]

Esto debería solucionarse usando el comando que nos recomienda Flutter Doctor `flutter doctor --android-licenses`, pero si el problema persiste debemos realizar la siguiente configuración.

Debemos instalar el `Android SDK Command-line Tools (lastet)`. Para esto abrimos Android Studio y realizamos la siguiente configuración dentro de `settings` en `File`.

[image: Settings de Android]

Luego de esa configuración obtenemos lo siguiente.

[image: Flutter doctor]